# Why does HTML button generate 'ul' node only once when clicked multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Let me clarify, my below code is *doing what I want.*

I'm working on a simple todo app. Right now, everytime the button is clicked on the page, it runs the **createListElem()** function. The first line of code inside this function appends our ul element to the body. However, it doesn't repeatedly add new ul elements when the button is clicked. It only adds li elements to that ul element.

Let me again clarify, *that is fine and is what I want it to do*.

Everytime we hit that button, we run the function. So in theory, everytime we hit that button, a new ul_node is appended to the body? Or is it because I intialized the variable holding the ul_node outside the function, it doesn't append a new ul_node?

Basically my question is: **Why when we click that button, the function appends one ul element to the page, rather than a ul element every button click?**

Hope I'm clear! My code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

    <title>Nick's Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="main-header">Nick's Todo List</h1>
    <div class="input-container">
        <input id="input-box" type="text" value="bro bro">
        <input onclick="createListElem()" id="add-btn" type="button">
        <select name="task-completion" id="task-completion">
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
            <option value="Uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const ul_node = document.createElement("ul");

function createListElem() {

    document.body.appendChild(ul_node);

    const box_value = document.getElementById('input-box').value;

    const task = document.createTextNode(box_value);

    const li_node = document.createElement('li');

    li_node.appendChild(task)

    ul_node.appendChild(li_node)

}
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps it's overwriting the same div?

Comment: I reread your question over and over again. May you rephrase your question. Thanks

Comment: `ul_node = document.createElement("ul");` needs to be INSIDE the `createListElem` function - otherwise, it's the same ul you are appending - `document.body.appendChild(ul_node);` just moves it if it's already in the DOM (though, in this case, it's going back to where it was) - but ... do you really want to create an new UL every time? no, so it's all good :p

Comment: as this code works like you want, the only issue would be if something else were subsequently appended to document.body ... calling this function again would move the UL to the end of body, past the other thing you appended, this may not be what you want ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `parentElement.appendChild(element)` the existing `element` is *moved* from its current location to the new location

The first time, this results in the element being added to the DOM

Second and subsequent calls simply moves the element from its current location in the DOM to the new location - in this case back to where it was, since it already is the last child of document.body

---

The only time this code could be a problem is if other elements are appended after this `UL` ... in that case, calling `createListElem` would move the UL element after those elements

One way to avoid this is to check if `ul` is already in the DOM - i.e. it has a `.parentElement` (or `.parentNode`) and only append it if it does not

```
const ul_node = document.createElement("ul");
function createListElem() {
    if (!ul_node.parentElement) {
        document.body.appendChild(ul_node);
    }
    // ... etc
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Everytime we hit that button, we run the function. So in theory,
> everytime we hit that button, a new ul_node is appended to the body?
> Or is it because I intialized the variable holding the ul_node outside
> the function, it doesn't append a new ul_node?

Yes, that's correct. The code to create the `ul` element exists outside of your function and is executed only once. It's the code within your callback function that runs every time you click the button. Now, the first time you click the button the new `ul` is appended to the `body`, but from there on, when you ask for the `ul` to be appended to the body, you are asking for the one that already exists to be appended and when that happens, append just moves the element from where it is to where you told it to go. Since where it is and where you are telling it to go are the same location, no new `ul` seems to appear.

If you want to create a new `ul` to add below the existing one each time, you'll need to move the `createElement` line into the function.

Comment: all good, except for the last sentence .... moving the `createElement` into the function will NOT "blow away" the old one - what would happen then is each call to createListElem would append a new UL after the last UL in document.body and add the LI etc into the new UL - the old UL will remain

Comment: Gotcha, this answers my question. Marked as answer. Thanks!

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, momentary brain fart. You're right. Answer updated.